# Counting self intersections of linestring using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, linestring

Is there a way of using PostgreSQL + PostGIS for finding the number of self intersections in a linestring?

I have a linestring that goes forward but in circles, and I need to find the number of times it crosses itself.

Comment: please add more details to your questions there are many ways to find self intersecting lines in postgis. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ST_IsValidReason probably helps, example documentation shows only one error per geometry so maybe you need to run it in recursive loop . see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_IsValidReason.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, but I think something like this might solve your problem (this wont work on multilines, but you could stdump them or squish them) :

```
SELECT  ID, 
        COUNT(*) AS theCOunt
FROM
(
  SELECT  id, 
          ST_Intersection(A.geom, B.geom) AS geom
  FROM
  (
    SELECT  xx.id,
            xx.id2,
            st_makeline(xx.l_start, xx.l_end) AS geom
     FROM 
     ( 
       SELECT  x.id,
               generate_series(1, st_npoints(x.geom) - 1) AS id2,
               st_pointn(x.geom, generate_series(1, st_npoints(x.geom) - 1)) AS l_start,
               st_pointn(x.geom, generate_series(2, st_npoints(x.geom))) AS l_end
       FROM 
       ( 
         SELECT  DATA_TABLE.id,
                 DATA_TABLE.geom 
         FROM DATA_TABLE
        ) AS X
     ) AS XX
 ) AS A
 INNER JOIN
 (
    SELECT  xx.id,
            xx.id2,
            st_makeline(xx.l_start, xx.l_end) AS geom
     FROM 
     ( 
       SELECT  x.id,
               generate_series(1, st_npoints(x.geom) - 1) AS id2,
               st_pointn(x.geom, generate_series(1, st_npoints(x.geom) - 1)) AS l_start,
               st_pointn(x.geom, generate_series(2, st_npoints(x.geom))) AS l_end
       FROM 
       ( 
         SELECT  DATA_TABLE.id,
                 DATA_TABLE.geom 
         FROM DATA_TABLE
        ) AS X
     ) AS XX
 ) AS B
ON A.ID = b.ID
   AND
   A.id2 <> B.id2
   AND
   A.id2 <> B.id2-1
   AND
   A.id2 < B.id2
   AND
   ST_INTERSECTS(A.geom, B.geom)
```

Comment: or something like that

Answer (score 1):

How about this (assume `test` is your linestring table):

First nodify the linestring, e.g. create vertices at each intersection while keeping the original vertices in tact.

```
CREATE TABLE node AS SELECT id, ST_Node(wkb_geometry) as wkb_geometry FROM test;
```

Count all distinct points in the new linestrings. Substracting the initial number of vertices from noded number should give you number of intersections.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (ST_DumpPoints(wkb_geometry)).geom, id FROM node) tmp  group by id;
```